# Binary Search doesn't give correct output

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search

> Getting wrong output of -1 and -1 it is going in the else section no compile time errors getting an output of -1
>
> ```
> > Here the code is going out of the loop for all test cases how?I am unable to understand what is the mistake as I am new to programming
> ```
>
> please help me I had asked a pretty similar question in linear search
>   This is iterative approach tried even
>   with recursive doesn't work.

```
int bin_search(int A[], int left, int right, int k)
{
    int found=0,mid;
    mid=(left+right)/2;
    if(right>=1)
    {
        if(k>A[left])
        {
            left=k;
            bin_search(A,mid+1,right,k);
        }
        else if(k<A[right])
        {
            right=k;
            bin_search(A,left,mid-1,k);
        }
        else if(A[mid]=k)
        {   
            return mid;
        }   

    }
   else return -1;
}
int main()
{int n;
 int A[]={1,2,3,4,5};
 int a=bin_search(A,0,n-1,4);
 printf("%d ",a);
}
```

Comment: You should _really_ invest a bit of time into trying to use consistent formatting. This is horrible to look at.

Comment: Read the compiler warnings. (If you didn't get a compiler warning, turn on compiler warnings.)

Comment: Format the narrative and the code please. We will spend about as much time answering this as you did asking it.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is about to be closed as it currently stands.

Comment: apply proper indentations to your code. it is very difficult to read.

Comment: Hope the current edit helps

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Amongst other things, the necessary `#include` statements are missing.

Comment: Iterative approach

Comment: your binary search function is full of logical errors. Firstly comparison is done with arr[mid] and the first if condition sould be right>=left and not right>=1

Comment: the variable `n` is not set to a known value, so it is unknown what `n-1` will evaluate to.

Comment: forgot to add the header file over here but in my actual code I have my header file

Comment: @user3629249 that was the problem thanks problem solved.Thanks a lot

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via one blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 (be consistent) blank lines.

Comment: you could eliminate the variable `n` and change the third parameter of the initial call to `bin_search() to: `sizeof( A ) / sizeof( A[0] )`

Comment: in the function: `bin_search()`, the 'k' parameter is the target to be found so why does the code contain such statements as: `left=k;`  and `right=k;`  The indexes `left` and `right` should never be assigned the target value (which is not an index)

Comment: variable and parameter names should indicate content or usage (or better, both) however, 'n' and 'k'  are meaningless even in the current context

Comment: There are plenty of other problems with the code, besides the usage of an un-initialized variable. And we are not interested in guessing which header files you used.  You need to explicitly state, as part of the code, which header files are included

Comment: @user3629249 yes after using the sizeof operator it is solved thanks alot and sorry for made editing and narative of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a correct code

```js
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int bin_search(int A[], int left, int right, int k)
   {
      int found=0,mid;
      mid=(left+right)/2;
      if(left <= right)
      {
         if(k>A[mid])
         {
            left=mid+1;
            bin_search(A,mid+1,right,k);
         }
         else if(k<A[mid])
         {
            right=mid-1;
            bin_search(A,left,mid-1,k);
         }
        else if(A[mid]=k)
        {   
            return mid;
        }   

     }
     else return -1;
}
int main()
{      int n = 5;
       int A[]={1,2,3,4,5};
       int a=bin_search(A,0,n-1,2);
       printf("%d ",a);
}
```

Comment: Sorry your code gives the exact same wrong output which I have been getting the output is -1 is this case.

Comment: initialize n with sizeof the array n=sizeof(arr)/ sizeof(arr[0]);

Comment: Why a c++ answer in a c question? c++ tag was removed 15 minutes before your answer.

Comment: Run code snippet is throwing an error but I am assuming because you used the wrong header file <iostream> for printf,I understood what your trying to say thanks alot!!

Comment: What's the matter with C++ or C . Have a C code now here http://ideone.com/aRhalC

Comment: There is an integer overflow error in this code: `mid=(left+right)/2` can overflow when left and right are large enough. You can prevent this by rewriting the expression, e.g. `left + (right - left) / 2`. This is one of the most typical errors when implementing sorting algorithms. That is one reason not to reimplement algorithms for which mature libraries are available.